Lubuntu 24.04, with UbuntuStudio low-latency-kernel installed, can't work with NVidia driver 550
This is just an FYI, or a bug-report, not a question.
Installing Lubuntu 24.04LTS,
then installing UbuntuStudio, with its low-latency kernel
( btw, the UbuntuStudio installer CANNOT uninstall that low-latency-kernel,
so that's another bug.. )
then installing the NVidia 550 driver,
the machine reboots into a state where the video is borked ( 1 display has a kind of low light, but nothing distinct/legible on it, the other is sleeping/off ).
Now I have to either reinstall, to eradicate that problem,
( because, as I say, the UbuntuStudio low-latency-kernel cannot be uninstalled through it,
& having to always remember to alter the boot in the Advanced choices of Grub, is annoying,
& every damn time I have to hard-reset the machine because I forgot, that's trashing the filesystems.. )
or find some method of bypassing the UbuntuStudio's installation of that kernel,
& rip it out directly.
This is on a Ryzen system.
There doesn't seem to be any method for bug-reporting on UbuntuStudio.org,
so I'm reporting it here.

Report UbuntuStudio bugs on https://bugs.launchpad.net  Adding a non-realtime driver to a real-time kernel can only produce two results: 1)your non-functioning video, or 2)A non-realtime system.
